# How to create app settings files for Angular 6?

Tags: angular

I want to implement the configuration settings like ASP.NET (AppSettings) which is no need of new build if any changes in AppSettings. 
Can anyone suggest me how to Implement this is in Angular 6.

Note : Configuration file should not  be visible to browser/Client

Comment: do you mean to set environment config ? if  then angular already has a environment folder

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you are trying to do? What type of things would be in this file? Angular already provides an environment.ts file. Is that what you are looking for? If so, you can find documentation here: https://angular.io/guide/build#using-environment-specific-variables-in-your-app

Comment: As per my requirements, My web application will point to Mock service for first month(For Validation), Once validation over , it will point to Actual third party services. So second time , we do not want to take new build for changing the URL

Answer (score 0):

These type of requirements are very common for web apps and correct way to handle it is exposing a service which will return all the configuration. Now lets discuss what are the benefits of this approach :

1. **Easy to configure and change** : we are calling it as a configuration which means these setting are configurable and there are chances that they are going to be changed in future. so these configurations should be configurable.
2. **No need of application build** : Since all the configuration setting is coming from server any change in configuration will not require a build.

You can not set your configuration in angular application since at the end the compilers converts these files in JS and user can see it very easily.

Definitely there is way to handle it on client side by putting all the changes in configuration files `environment.ts` and `environment.prod.ts` but with any future change in configuration you have to rebuild the app and which is again cause a deployment, which does not solve your problem.

Comment: Exactly @kedar  we do not want to take new build  but  Service call may lead to performance issue .

Comment: I don't thing so a single service @ the time of app load will not cause much performance issue. But you can't achieve it client side without causing app build.

Comment: Production build , is it possible to view the configuration ? or configuration will be encrypted